# Dojo: NumberSpinner Issue

Tags: dojo

I created this NumberSpinner widget:

```
<input name="form_action_fy" id="form_action_fy" value="2010" 
    data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberSpinner" 
    data-dojo-smallDelta="1" 
    data-dojo-largeDelta="1" 
    data-dojo-constraints="{min:2010,max:2030,places:0}" />
```

When I load the page, the widget shows as expected. However, there are a couple of issues:

- The value is empty and not 2010.
- When I press the decrease button on the empty widget, I get 9000000000000000 and when I increase on the empty widget, I get -9000000000000000. It doesn't stick to the min/max specified.
- And, the smallDelta and largeDelta do not work either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the new widget attribute style the properties that are passed to the constructor function are all put in the `data-dojo-props` attribute, instead of the ad-hoc attributes of old. In the cases where the docs still point to the older declarative style you might get better luck by looking for the programatic style examples instead.

```html
<input name="form_action_fy" id="form_action_fy"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberSpinner"
    data-dojo-props="
        value:2010,
        smallDelta:5,
        largeDelta:10,
        constraints:{min:2010,max:2200,places:0}"
/>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/missingno/cQfFt/

Do note that in Dojo 1.6 a couple of widgets are still in transition so some attributes might need to be duplicated in prop and attribute form. Things should be allright in 1.7 though.

Comment: Technically if you stick to putting all properties in `data-dojo-props`, there is no duplication necessary; it's if you also want to degrade gracefully that you need to put things both in standard HTML attributes and in `data-dojo-props`.  Note that this is only applicable to `data-dojo-type` on Dojo 1.6; 1.7 no longer has this issue, nor does the legacy method of declarative instantiation with `dojoType`.